# BR() tag in default value formula of a text area (long) field not working

Tags: formula

I have a text area (long) field.  It contains the default value "Text1"  & BR() & "Text2".

It never renders the br() tag correctly, the final result is always 'text1 BR() text2'.   Field type is text area(long).  Setup  to display 2 lines.

What am I doing wrong here?  I've tried both "text1" & BR() & "Text2" and "Text1"&BR()&"Text2".  And according to the documentation it should work.

Comment: Is it for `apex:inputTextarea`?

Comment: Nope, it's just a default formula value for a text field.  No apex involved.

Comment: How do you show the text, where is it broken? At custom vf-page or on the standard layout page?

Comment: I just tested your code `"Text1" & BR() & "Text2"` for an account object and it works fine for me. At the account creation standard page i can see an input text (long) with Text1 and Text2 with brake in between.

Comment: Is this on a standard page or Visualforce?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `+` instead of `&`?

Comment: the `+`did the trick.  Thanks @user31!
FWIW - this was on standard page layout.  No Visualforce at all.

Comment: woop woop! what you did [appears to be fully supported](http://na11.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/customize_functions_a_h.htm#Concatenate) - wanna raise a Case?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using this formula field on a Visualforce page with an `apex:outputText` try using the [`escape`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_outputText.htm) attribute.

So, something like:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!Custom_Object__c.Custom_Formula_Field__c}" escape="false"/>
```