# BR() Function Not working in SFDC Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, formula, html

I have a flow that uses the BR() function in a text resource. However, it displays the actual `<br>` text when updating a record. I've tried both using a Rich Text Field and a Long Text Area field, but both are returning the `<br>` function. I've done this before on a long text area so i don't think that's the issue.

Here's what it looks the formula looks like:

```
{!$Record.Sequence_Name__c}&BR()&{!$Record.Finished_Sequences__c}
```

Here's what it looks like on the record:

[image: example image]

Comment: This is what it looks like on the record: david test<br>

Comment: Since the text is output literally, have you tried using `\n` instead?

Comment: Have you checked this? - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/298222/br-not-returning-a-line-break-in-flows  - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8708/br-tag-in-default-value-formula-of-a-text-area-long-field-not-working